# Multisite - big hosting package or several hosting packages?

Tags: multisite, hosting

When I want to create a mutlisite on which I can create mutliple sub-sites with different domain names, do I have to buy a hosting package for each of these sub-sites or can I just link the domain name to the corresponding sub-site of Wordpress MU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of a WordPress Multisite install it is not even possible to have two different hosting packages for one Multisite.

A Multisite install is actually the same as a single WordPress install. The only difference is the configuration in the `wp-config.php` and in the options. The database used for all the Sites is also the same.

The different domains you use are all sent to the same Multisite installation.

Having two different hosting packages means also having (at least) two different storage spaces and databases, so you lose the advantage of Multisite in the first place.

Therefor the only things you have to watch out for when choosing a hosting package for a WordPress Multisite are:

- Handling of Domains (Possibility of having more than one Domain, creating Subdomains if needed and directing them to the right directory)
- Availability of Webspace (depending on your plans for your Multisite, you may need a lot of storage)
- General stuff concerning Webspace (availability, speed, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see you have experience with this. My main concern now is how this solution works for SEO, have you got experience with that aswell?

Comment: @Broeiend, this is a new question.... ;)

Comment: ok sorry, I'll create a new one :)

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on your hosting. Been a long time since I last used shared hosting but AFAIK you might pay to have extra domains on the plan, but subdomains are free.

Actually there is nothing special about wordpress multisite here, you either can or can not have additional domain and subdomains on your plan, the technology you are going to use is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, it is not even possible to have multiple hosting packages with one multisite installation ;)

Comment: @fischi As a separate answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can point your sub domains to corresponding domains by domain mapping,
You can use the plugin [wordpress-mu-domain-mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

Comment: Thanks for this plugin, it seems to me this should be native on multisite. Anyhow, no problem to use a plugin though :)